# Writing <code> snippets with TinyMCE Editor and render using CodeMirror code highlighter

Tags: php, tinymce, codemirror

Please have a look at the following URL
http://sribasu.com/blog/2_programming-tutorials/5_getting-value-of-radio-button-and-checkbox-using-jquery-cross-browser.html (fortunately I managed to show the codes properly on this page now, by inserting \n from DB)

I'm using TinyMCE Editor to create content of my web pages. Although, I'm struggling with a strange issue. My Code Highlighter plugin CodeMirror expects newline (\n) character as line separator, instead of 
 tags. But, TinyMCE editor will never let me insert \n as newline. How can I create a HTML content (in my case, my blog post) with TinyMCE editor, so that it renders all the [Enter] key press as \n instead of 
 tag, when I'm writing within  tag?

Comment: are you using Mac? line breaks on a Mac system will always be rendered as a carriage return (`\r`) only, so this may be a system dependent issue.

Comment: No I'm testing on Windows and Unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about CodeMirror, but is it possible to modify the tinymce code BEFORE you give it to codeMirror? In this case you would have alook at the end of paragraphs and insert a `\n` there.

Comment: Yes, that's possible for me. I can process the Code generated by TinyMCE before saving it to database. Can you tell me how to use a proper Regular Expression to replace all the `<br>` and `<br />` tags with `\n` inside `<code>` tags?

Comment: no regex needed, you can use this content.replace(/\<br\>/, '\n').replace(/<br \/>/,'\n');